# Javascript, cannot access JSON property

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string received from websocket :

```
{  
   "type":"newLoan",
   "cartItems":{  
      "numberOfItems":null,
      "bookList":[  
         {  
            "id":"1",
            "title":"The Count of Monte Cristo",
            "author":"Alexandre Dumas     ",
            "genre":"Comedy",
            "returnDate":"January 15"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This result is shown after `console.log(receivedMessage)`, but when I try to access type property by `console.log(receivedMessage["type"])` it gives me undefined.

Still the same with `console.log(receivedMessage.type)`.

How could I access the type property?

Comment: Works fine [codepen](http://codepen.io/AlexChar/pen/NPGLmQ)

Comment: Is it maybe still a string instead of an object? Try `console.log(JSON.parse(receivedMessage).type)`.

Comment: Please post the complete code if possible so we can be able to help you.

Comment: var obj = {  
   "type":"newLoan",
   "cartItems":{  
      "numberOfItems":null,
      "bookList":[  
         {  
            "id":"1",
            "title":"The Count of Monte Cristo",
            "author":"Alexandre Dumas     ",
            "genre":"Comedy",
            "returnDate":"January 15"
         }
      ]
   }
};
console.log(obj.type); works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an issue with the headers that are being sent along with your string, if the content type isn't set to `application/json` or the javascript equivalent then it will be treated as a string and no a json object

Comment: But still, I should be able to parse it in javascript, using JSON.parse(), no?
Doing this I am getting a parsing error.

Comment: No. If you get a json string returned with the `text/html` content type then your javascript will completely ignore that the string is json and treat it as one long text string and that it why console logging it works but when you try and access the objects it will give `undefined` as it isn't being treated as a json object that javascript can interact with

Comment: If I go higher, that snippet of json is cut from a bigger json code. Would that have something to do with my error?

Comment: It shouldn't but if you can access some parts of the json response then it wont be your headers

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
JSON.parse(receivedMessage).type
```